# how to set default_value for list_boolean field equal to 1, not 0?

Tags: entities

I'm using this code to add a `list_boolean` field to my user entities on D7.20.  The field is added, but the default value shows up as *unchecked*, whereas I've tried to be careful with

> 'default_value' => array(0 => array('value' => 1)),

to make it show up *checked*.

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

**Update**: Actually this seems fine, see explanation in answer.

```
function MYMODULE_create_user_field_binary($myField_name, $label, $desc) {
  $field = array(
   'field_name' => $myField_name,
   'module' => 'list',
  'type' => 'list_boolean',
     'settings' => array(
     'allowed_values' => array(
       0 => '0',
       1 => '1',
      ),
     'allowed_values_function' => ''
     ),
     );
  field_create_field($field);

  $field_instance = array(
      'field_name' => $myField_name,
      'entity_type' => 'user',
      'bundle' => 'user',
      'label' => t($label),
      'description' => t($desc),
      'default_value' => array(0 => array('value' => 1)),
      'widget' => array(
        'active' => 1,
        'module' => 'options',
        'settings' => array(
                'display_label' => 1,
                ),
        'type' => 'options_onoff',
       ),
      'settings' => array(
      'user_register_form' => 1,
    )
    );
  field_create_instance($field_instance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the behavior here is a bit weird.  The box shows up *unchecked* when the field examining an existing user (e.g. when browsing `/user/1/edit` when logged in as admin), but it does show up as *checked* when browsing to `/user/register` when not logged in.  So that was a little confusing.

Upon further investigation, the new field isn't populated at all for existing users, i.e. the database entries simply don't exist.  So those will have to be created manually it seems -- at which point I can specify whatever value I want as the "default".  In my case:

```
INSERT INTO field_data_MYFIELD
(entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id,language,delta,MYFIELD_value)
SELECT 'user', 'user', 0, users.uid, users.uid, 'und', 0, 1 from users;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Joe
If you want the value is 1 by default, after you create your field successfully try to add this code after:

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u');      
$query->fields('u', array('uid'));
$result = $query->execute();
while($record = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
   db_query("INSERT INTO {field_data_MYFIELD}
   (entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id,language,delta, MYFIELD_value) VALUES('user', 'user', 0, :uid, :uid, 'und', 0, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entity_type='user', bundle='user', deleted=0, entity_id=:uid, revision_id=:uid, language='und', delta=0, MYFIELD_value =1 ", array(':uid' => $record['uid']));
   $cid = 'field:user:' . $record['uid'];
   cache_clear_all($cid, 'cache_field');
}
```

Pay attention you should add {} for the table name in case there are prefix in tables, also I use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because if there is value before for the same user it will get updated and will not broke the code.

Also After update this value you should clear the user field cache so it will reflect in the user profile.

Last thing you should add this `hook_user_insert` to make the value 1 for the future user registrations:

```
function hook_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  db_query("INSERT INTO {field_data_MYFIELD}
  (entity_type, bundle, deleted, entity_id, revision_id,language,delta,MYFIELD_value) VALUES('user', 'user', 0, :uid, :uid, 'und', 0, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entity_type='user', bundle='user', deleted=0, entity_id=:uid, revision_id=:uid, language='und', delta=0, MYFIELD_value=1 ", array(':uid' => $account->uid));
  $cid = 'field:user:' . $account->uid;
  cache_clear_all($cid, 'cache_field');
}
```